# Numpy: About the second rule of numpy.ufunc.reduceat?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

From the [docs - v1.14](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) the second rule is

- if indices[i] >= indices[i + 1], the i-th generalized “row” is simply a[indices[i]].

So how will this being used? Is there any real example?

I meant, there must(?) be some real situations that fit what this rule is doing, then we defined the rule to fit them, so what's that situation?

Comment: Take `np.add.reduceat([1, 2, 3], [2, 1])`. 2 is greater than 1, so the first reduction is just whatever is at index 2.

Comment: @miradulo: Is there any reason why it's designed like this? I meant when someone designed this function, there must be a situation need this rule? Nice to see you again btw :)

Comment: There is some interesting discussion about `np.ufunc.reduceat` in [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/834) GitHub issue. I don't think you're going to get any kind of satisfying general answer for this behavior - it is what it is. A number of NumPy devs actually want to deprecate `reduceat` altogether.

Comment: The code needs to deal with the situation in one way or other.  You or I could give it indices like that.  It can try to return some 'reasonable' value, or it can raise an error.

Comment: @miradulo: Thank you for the link, I'm reading it. So should I delete this question? Sorry for my bad question...

Comment: @Niing IMO I'm not sure how answerable your question is, so you can if you'd like. But your call, and no need to apologize!

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 examples make use of this rule.

In the 2nd example, the 2d array, it shows explicitly what `[0, 3, 1, 2, 0]` produces

```
# [row1 + row2 + row3]          0:3
# [row4]                        3
# [row2]                        1:2
# [row3]                        2 
# [row1 + row2 + row3 + row4]   0:end
```

In the first example, this rule is partly hidden by the [::2] indexing.

Without that:

```
In [183]: np.add.reduceat(np.arange(8),[0,4, 1,5, 2,6, 3,7])
Out[183]: array([ 6,  4, 10,  5, 14,  6, 18,  7])
```

There's [0:4]sum, [4], [1,5]sum, [5], [2:6]sum, [6], [3:7]sum, 7

Selecting just the odd results, we get 4 range sums:

```
In [184]: _[::2]
Out[184]: array([ 6, 10, 14, 18])

In [187]: [np.arange(0,4).sum(),np.arange(1,5).sum(),np.arange(2,6).sum()]
Out[187]: [6, 10, 14]
```

Comment: So the 4, 5, 6, 7 in your first example is just for separation? I when I for example one know 4 is at [i] then he knows (accumulative) result of the range ends at 4 is at [i-1]?

Comment: Separation isn't quite the right term, but they are surplus values when the goal is the sequence of overlapping sums.  The spaces in `[0,4, 1,5, ...]` are for our convenience, not the code's.  Otherwise we are stuck with contiguous, non-overlapping groupings.